# What should the timestamp be identified before setting timezones in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: timezone, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I know Apache IoTDB can setup different timezones of time series data. Can I understand that when deploying Apache IoTDB in different timezones, all the different timezones can use the default timestamp (which is relative to 1970 timestamp). When querying, we use date and time zone to view time series data in different timezone settings. Is there any problem with this idea? The timestamp itself in IoTDB do not need to identify any timezone beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the timestamps in Apache IoTDB are based on timezone 0 (which means the standard time). If you do not set different timezones for different servers, then the timestamps will be the same and there is no need to distinguish anything. Only if you set different timezones will the time reflected in the database be different.